# Most accurate, but "cheapest" way to measure C++ code?

Tags: c++, boost, cpu

I'd like a way to measure C++ code as accurately as possible. I did see boost has a high resolution clock but the boost documentation says it's an expensive clock in terms of performance- kinda defeating the purpose:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html

What other ways are there? Is there any way to measure in CPU cycles??

Comment: [Boost.Stopwatches](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/ReviewScheduleLibraries#Boost.Stopwatches) is pending review for inclusion in Boost. That will probably become the best option.

Comment: What is it you want to measure? Code execution time? For what purpose?

Comment: Would a profiler suit your needs ?

Comment: The "classic" solution is to check the difference between to calls to the `clock` function.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker probably but I just wanted to know for a smaller scale, excluding profilers, is there a c++ code solution?

Comment: Do you want to measure the elapsed (real) time or the CPU usage time? Note that the elapsed time isn't accurate when you run other tasks on the same machine, while the CPU usage time should be more accurate in this case (at least in theory).

Comment: @Everyone, ideally I would like to count CPU cycles without having to use a profiler- either using OS calls or C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from your question if you want external or internal profiling.

For external profiling, you have Quantify (or its successor) on Windows, and gprof on any unix with g++ and friends. If you use Solaris you even have dtrace, which you can attach to a running application to do statistical profiling.

If you're looking for internal profiling, `gettimeofday` on Solaris/Linux should be quite performant enough for anything except inside a tight loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GCC, try GNU profiler (gprof) http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/.
Gprof probably gives you the most accurate results.

Taking the difference of start/end time in a function is less accurate to due context switches (b/w process or threads).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows use QueryPerformanceCounter().

On Solaris use gethrtime().

On other UNIX use gettimeofday().

Of course you should wrap them in a class so your code only uses the class
and not the methods directly.

We use a class like

```
class dbbHighResTimer {
public:
    dbbHighResTimer(); // Does call set()
    dbbHighResTimer( int ); // Does not call set()
    void    set();
    friend double operator - ( const dbbHighResTimer &, const dbbHighResTimer & );
    friend int compare( const dbbHighResTimer &, const dbbHighResTimer & );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is for profiling on Windows, use rdtsc instruction, provided it is accurate on your CPU (see [How to detect if RDTSC returns a constant rate counter value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509727/how-to-detect-if-rdtsc-returns-a-constant-rate-counter-value) for a discussion). It is a lot faster than QueryPerformanceCounter.