# System.out of nanoTime is incorrect?

Tags: java, time

I'm doing a `private Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.nanoTime());` in one of my entities when the object is created.

If I system.out the timestamp, I'm getting values like;

```
2282-08-24 11:25:00.506
2286-04-16 01:47:35.882
```

What is wrong here?

`System.currentTimeMillis()` gives the correct date, but I need more accuracy. 
 What could be wrong here??

Comment: Nothing, it just behaves as specified: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp(long)

Comment: Have you bothered reading the documentation for System.currentTimeMillis(), System.nanoTime() and the Timestamp constructor? That should have answered your question in less time it took you to write this question.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11599287/1504523) answer to get a brief overview about `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`System.nanoTime()` is a completely abstract way of measuring time, it has something to do with the number of CPU cycles since the computer was started. It's completely unrelated to `java.util.Date` that uses epoch time (number of milliseconds since 1970).

You are free to compare two different values of `System.nanoTime()` to get very accurate time measurements (theoretically up to 1 nanosecond), but the absolute value taken alone is useless.

Comment: I was not aware of this! Anyway is there an alternative to create the date with accuracy better than millis?

Comment: @membersound: [JavaDoc on `Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) (emphasis mine): "*The class `Date` represents a specific instant in time, with **millisecond precision**.*" | downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Yes, you can create a higher precision than millis. It is not straightforward, but the gist of it, is recording the System.nanoTime at boot, then calculate the cost the of the actual System.nanoTime operation. You would then record a number of system.currenttimeinmillis as well as system.nanoTime and calibrate them using the average diff. And then, whenever you want the actual time in nanoseconds, you would do a System.nanoTime() and withdraw some calculations. I have it code. Maybe I can pull it out.

Answer (score 1):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.

[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp expects new Timestamp(miliseconds). If you give it nanoseconds (new Timestamp(nanoseconds) ---> 1000 times greater) you obtain a timestamp 1000 times in the future, whatever that means. This is the reason because the dates obtained are in the year 2282