# Akka message passing timing

Tags: scala, akka, artificial-life

I am working on an artificial life simulation with Scala and Akka and so far I've been super happy with both. I am having some issues with timing however that I can't quite explain.

At the moment, each animal in my simulation is a pair of actors (animal + brain). Typically, these two actors take turns (animal sends sensor input to brain, waits for result, acts on it and starts over). Every now and then however, animals need to interact with each other to eat each other or reproduce.

The one thing that is odd to me is the timing. It turns out that sending a message from one animal to another is a LOT slower (about 100x) than sending from animal to brain. This puts my poor predators and sexually active animals at a disadvantage as opposed to the vegetarians and asexual creatures (disclaimer: I am vegetarian myself but I think there are better reasons for being a vegetarian than getting stuck for a bit while trying to hunt...).

I extracted a minimal code snippet that demonstrates the problem:

```
package edu.blindworld.test

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Actor}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.Random

class Animal extends Actor {
  val brain = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Brain]))
  var animals: Option[List[ActorRef]] = None

  var brainCount = 0
  var brainRequestStartTime = 0L
  var brainNanos = 0L

  var peerCount = 0
  var peerRequestStartTime = 0L
  var peerNanos = 0L

  override def receive = {
    case Go(all) =>
      animals = Some(all)
      performLoop()
    case BrainResponse =>
      brainNanos += (System.nanoTime() - brainRequestStartTime)
      brainCount += 1
      // Animal interactions are rare
      if (Random.nextDouble() < 0.01) {
        // Send a ping to a random other one (or ourselves). Defer our own loop
        val randomOther = animals.get(Random.nextInt(animals.get.length))
        peerRequestStartTime = System.nanoTime()
        randomOther ! PeerRequest
      } else {
        performLoop()
      }
    case PeerResponse =>
      peerNanos += (System.nanoTime() - peerRequestStartTime)
      peerCount += 1
      performLoop()
    case PeerRequest =>
      sender() ! PeerResponse
    case Stop =>
      sender() ! StopResult(brainCount, brainNanos, peerCount, peerNanos)
      context.stop(brain)
      context.stop(self)
  }

  def performLoop() = {
    brain ! BrainRequest
    brainRequestStartTime = System.nanoTime()
  }
}

class Brain extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case BrainRequest =>
      sender() ! BrainResponse
  }
}

case class Go(animals: List[ActorRef])
case object Stop
case class StopResult(brainCount: Int, brainNanos: Long, peerCount: Int, peerNanos: Long)

case object BrainRequest
case object BrainResponse

case object PeerRequest
case object PeerResponse

object ActorTest extends App {
  println("Sampling...")
  val system = ActorSystem("Test")
  val animals = (0 until 50).map(i => system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Animal]))).toList
  animals.foreach(_ ! Go(animals))
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  val futureStats = animals.map(_.ask(Stop).mapTo[StopResult])
  val stats = futureStats.map(Await.result(_, Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
  val brainCount = stats.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.brainCount)
  val brainNanos = stats.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _.brainNanos)
  val peerCount = stats.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.peerCount)
  val peerNanos = stats.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _.peerNanos)
  println("Average time for brain request: " + (brainNanos / brainCount) / 1000000.0 + "ms (sampled from " + brainCount + " requests)")
  println("Average time for peer pings: " + (peerNanos / peerCount) / 1000000.0 + "ms (sampled from " + peerCount + " requests)")
  system.shutdown()
}
```

This is what happens here:

- I am creating 50 pairs of animal/brain actors
- They are all launched and run for 5 seconds
- Each animal does an infinite loop, taking turns with its brain
- In 1% of all runs, an animal sends a ping to a random other animal and waits for its reply. Then, it continues its loop with its brain
- Each request to the brain and to peer is measured, so that we can get an average
- After 5 seconds, everything is stopped and the timings for brain-requests and pings to peers are compared

On my dual core i7 I am seeing these numbers:

```
Average time for brain request: 0.004708ms (sampled from 21073859 requests)

Average time for peer pings: 0.66866ms (sampled from 211167 requests)
```

So pings to peers are 165x slower than requests to brains. I've been trying lots of things to fix this (e.g. priority mailboxes and warming up the JIT), but haven't been able to figure out what's going on. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I notice you set brainRequestStartTime _after_ you send the BrainRequest msg, but set peerRequestStartTime _before_ sending the PeerRequest msg - are you sure the discrepancy isn't just the time it takes to execute the PeerRequest message send?

Comment: You could use a `PriorityMailbox`.

Comment: Shadowlands: I moved peerRequestStartTime down but it didn't make a difference. Putting a message on some actor's queue seems to be nearly instantaneous

Comment: johny: I tried to subclass UnboundedPriorityMailbox and prioritize peer messages (requests and responses over everything else), but I couldn't measure any difference. I *think* that makes sense as mailbox size shouldn't really be a problem as BrainResponses shouldn't be accumulating, so worst case any PeerRequest should have one BrainResponse ahead of it.

Comment: I may have missed your intent.. `System.nanoTime` is slightly slower. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052316/. Check whether `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis)` is faster.

Comment: This mirrors nature to a certain extend, doesn't it ? Not taking reflexes into account, messages from animal to brain are faster than from animal to animal. If the target brain belongs to the source animal, that is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ask pattern to handle the message. In your code, the BrainRequest was sent to the brain actor and then it sent back the BrainResponse. The problem was here. The BrainResponse was not that BrainRequest's response. Maybe it was previous BrainRequest's response.

The following code uses the ask pattern and the perf result is almost same.

```
package edu.blindworld.test

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Actor}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

class Animal extends Actor {
  val brain = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Brain]))
  var animals: Option[List[ActorRef]] = None

  var brainCount = 0
  var brainRequestStartTime = 0L
  var brainNanos = 0L

  var peerCount = 0
  var peerRequestStartTime = 0L
  var peerNanos = 0L

  override def receive = {
    case Go(all) =>
      animals = Some(all)
      performLoop()
    case PeerRequest =>
      sender() ! PeerResponse
    case Stop =>
      sender() ! StopResult(brainCount, brainNanos, peerCount, peerNanos)
      context.stop(brain)
      context.stop(self)
  }

  def performLoop(): Unit = {
    brainRequestStartTime = System.nanoTime()
    brain.ask(BrainRequest)(10.millis) onSuccess {
      case _ =>
        brainNanos += (System.nanoTime() - brainRequestStartTime)
        brainCount += 1
        // Animal interactions are rare
        if (Random.nextDouble() < 0.01) {
          // Send a ping to a random other one (or ourselves). Defer our own loop
          val randomOther = animals.get(Random.nextInt(animals.get.length))
          peerRequestStartTime = System.nanoTime()
          randomOther.ask(PeerRequest)(10.millis) onSuccess {
            case _ =>
              peerNanos += (System.nanoTime() - peerRequestStartTime)
              peerCount += 1
              performLoop()
          }
        } else {
          performLoop()
        }
    }
  }
}

class Brain extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case BrainRequest =>
      sender() ! BrainResponse
  }
}

case class Go(animals: List[ActorRef])
case object Stop
case class StopResult(brainCount: Int, brainNanos: Long, peerCount: Int, peerNanos: Long)

case object BrainRequest
case object BrainResponse

case object PeerRequest
case object PeerResponse

object ActorTest extends App {
  println("Sampling...")
  val system = ActorSystem("Test")
  val animals = (0 until 50).map(i => system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Animal]))).toList
  animals.foreach(_ ! Go(animals))
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  val futureStats = animals.map(_.ask(Stop).mapTo[StopResult])
  val stats = futureStats.map(Await.result(_, Duration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
  val brainCount = stats.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.brainCount)
  val brainNanos = stats.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _.brainNanos)
  val peerCount = stats.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.peerCount)
  val peerNanos = stats.foldLeft(0L)(_ + _.peerNanos)
  println("Average time for brain request: " + (brainNanos / brainCount) / 1000000.0 + "ms (sampled from " + brainCount + " requests)")
  println("Average time for peer pings: " + (peerNanos / peerCount) / 1000000.0 + "ms (sampled from " + peerCount + " requests)")
  system.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks a lot for your input.

I tried your solution and indeed the times are the same now, but the total message throughput went down by 15x, so I'd rather not switch everything over to that. I guess the ask pattern is a lot more expensive due to the temporary inbox that needs to be created.

Comment: I also verified what you suggested about wrong correlating of BrainRequests. To do that, I put the timestamp in the request and send it back in the response:

sending: `brain ! BrainRequest(System.nanoTime())`
receiving: `case BrainRequest(startNanos) =>
      sender() ! BrainResponse(startNanos)`

But that gives me the exact same timings as my original code.