# Timing method causing code to run slow

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization

I'm working on optimizing a little java program I made for Christmas. I was testing the amount of time it takes to run the methods and one of them, Snow_AI, is taking 1234567 nano seconds to run.

The issues is with the counter method:

```
public boolean Count() {
    if (CreateCnt > CreateTime) {
        CreateCnt = 0;
        return true;
    } else {
        CreateCnt = CreateCnt + 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is how I'm making the calls:

```
MethTmr1 = System.nanoTime();
    if (Snw.Count()) {
        MethTmr = System.nanoTime();
        Snw.Snow_AI();
        MethTPS = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - MethTmr);
    }
    try{
        MethTPS1 = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - MethTmr1);
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

when I move the timing calls inside the If statement it changed the time to run to less than 5000. Anyone know why the counter method is causing this to happen?

Comment: care to share how you measure that? Please show both ways you measured that.

Comment: `Tmr = System.nanoTime();` before the method call and `TPS = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - Tmr);` After the call. its what i use to measure frame rate and Ticks per second

Comment: Where do you measure time to run? I only see code like 1/time which would get lower with greater time...?

Comment: in the TPS variable: `TPS = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - Tmr);`
it works, i have used it before on a course project testing.

Comment: But thats **inversed** time. Bigger is shorter. How does your code look if you include the if?

Comment: you mean the if that seams to cause the issues? that's the last section of code in the question.

Comment: Can you add your output please? I'm confused what you measure where. MethTPS1 will include the whole messurement-code for MethTPS so it's counting **way more** than the if.

Comment: i can give you a file to down load if that will help? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_OnW-7IrSM9UjlYY3cyU2k1QU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: just to clarify I did do the measuring separately, i just put the code like that so you could see how i measured them both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measurement is flawed.

Check this:  [Why is System.nanoTime() way slower (in performance) than System.currentTimeMillis()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052316/why-is-system-nanotime-way-slower-in-performance-than-system-currenttimemill)

And then look at your code:

```
MethTmr1 = System.nanoTime();
if (Snw.Count()) {
    //expensive! Added to outer time
    MethTmr = System.nanoTime();
    Snw.Snow_AI();
     //expensive! Added to outer time
    MethTPS = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - MethTmr);
}
try{
    MethTPS1 = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - MethTmr1);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Baseline. Your MethTPS1 includes your (fast) getCount(), your Snow_AI() and **two tcalls to System.nanoTime()**

Try it this way once:

```
MethTmr1 = System.nanoTime();
if (Snw.Count()) {
    //expensive! Added to outer time
    //MethTmr = System.nanoTime();
    Snw.Snow_AI();
     //expensive! Added to outer time
    //MethTPS = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - MethTmr);
}
try{
    MethTPS1 = 1000000000 / (System.nanoTime() - MethTmr1);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: i did do the 2 timers on separate runs, i just did the code like that to show the way i'm testing :)

Comment: also the code is only there for testing and will be removed once the issues has been fixed.

Comment: I can only work with what I see - please then share what you really measure. how many iterations do you do for your test?

Comment: you right in what you said about the testing. it's not my AI method that is causing the slow down. when i do the testing i put the `system.nanotime()`  around the method to test and then run the program for 500 to 5000 iterations and then i move onto the next method and do the same. in this one i did the same but forgot to remove the 1000000000 / so like you said it was inverses.

Comment: the AI method actually runs at 240 nanoseconds and its my Snow_move method that's causing the issue. I'm not sure there is much i can do for it though because it has to move 20,000 flakes :) thanks for the help. even if i was a bit blinded :)

Comment: Watching snowflakes all day would make you snow blind ;-) Merry Christmas ;-)

Comment: merry Christmas to you too :)