# Measure runtime of a method handled by bukkit.event.Listener

Tags: java, performance, listener, bukkit, eventhandler

I need to accurately measure in ms (`#.### ms`), exactly how long a void method takes to run, without the measurement impacting the results.

Normally I would simply do something like:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
```

This won't work because my code never calls the method directly; it only defines it.

```
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;

public class BlockListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOWEST, ignoreCancelled = true)
    public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {

    //...
    }
}
```

In the context of certain methods in this Minecraft Bukkit server I'm working on, 1ms is significant, meaning I need high precision to measure and then optimize time-sensitive methods.

So, surely adding any code inside the method could affect the runtime of the method?

What is the best way to measure this? Please and thank you

*Running Paper/Spigot with ProtocolLib (1.16.5)*

Answer (score 1):

Performance measurement will always affect your performance, that's why it's I would suggest making this feature togglable. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19052481/4655217), calling `System.nanoTime()` two times per method will take approximately 200 CPU clock cycles, which is not a big overhead.

But after measuring the execution time, you need to save it somewhere or print a log. Usually, I/O operations are the most expensive, thus it's better to avoid blocking outputs in your method. For this purpose, you can utilize `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` or other implementations of thread-safe pipes (like [Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) or [JCTools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools)) and log captured results in separate daemon thread.

### Implementation proposal

```
public class ListenerPerformanceAuditor implements Listener {

    private final BlockingQueue<Long> executionTimeQueue;
    private final Listener auditedListener;

    public ListenerPerformanceAuditor(
            Listener auditedListener,
            BlockingQueue<Long> executionTimeQueue
    ) {
        this.auditedListener = auditedListener;
        this.executionTimeQueue = executionTimeQueue;
    }

    public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        auditedListener.onPlace(event);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
        if(!executionTimeQueue.offer(duration)) {
            // if measuring each and every request isn't necessary,
            // this block can be eliminated, otherwise add error handling logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about printing to stdout with println()? About how long does this take? Would it be similarly insignificant like with the delay from getting nanoTime inside the method?

Comment: Printing to console performance is comparable with `ArrayBlockingQueue#offer` performance in single-threaded application, but `System.out.println` is a synchronized operation that may lead to performance degradation in a multi-threaded system when more than one threads try to write into console.
Also, you can print directly in `ListenerPerformanceAuditor`, but in a thread pool, so no queue is needed and performance remains stable