# Why QueryperformanceCounter timed different from wall clock?

Tags: delphi, performancecounter

Hi I am using QueryperformanceCounter to time a block of code in Delphi. For some reason, the 
Millisecond number I got by using QueryPerformanceCounter is quite different from my wall clock time by using a stopwatch. For example The stopwatch give me about 33 seconds, which seems right if not accuracy, but using QueryPerofomanceCounter will give me a number like 500 Milliseconds.

When step though my code, I can see that QueryPerformanceFrequencygives me correct CPU frequency for my CPU, 2.4G for Core2 E6600. So if the tick number is correct, `(tick number / Freq) * 1000` should give me correct execution time for the code I am timing, but why not?

I know that for the code I am trying to timing, QeuryPerformanceCounter is probably over-killing as it took seconds rather than MillionSeconds, but I am more interested in understanding the reason for the time difference between wall clock and QueryPerormanceCounter.

My Hardware is E6600 Core2 and OS is Windows 7 X64 if it is relevant.

```
unit PerformanceTimer;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, DateUtils;

type TPerformanceTimer = class
  private
    fFrequency : TLargeInteger;
    fIsRunning: boolean;
    fIsHighResolution: boolean;
    fStartCount, FstopCount : TLargeInteger;
    procedure SetTickStamp(var lInt : TLargeInteger) ;
    function GetElapsedTicks: TLargeInteger;
    function GetElapsedMiliseconds: TLargeInteger;
  public
    constructor Create(const startOnCreate : boolean = false) ;
    procedure Start;
    procedure Stop;
    property IsHighResolution : boolean read fIsHighResolution;
    property ElapsedTicks : TLargeInteger read GetElapsedTicks;
    property ElapsedMiliseconds : TLargeInteger read GetElapsedMiliseconds;
    property IsRunning : boolean read fIsRunning;
end;

implementation

constructor TPerformanceTimer.Create(const startOnCreate : boolean = false) ;
begin
  inherited Create;

  fIsRunning := false;

  fIsHighResolution := QueryPerformanceFrequency(fFrequency) ;
  if NOT fIsHighResolution then
    fFrequency := MSecsPerSec;

  if startOnCreate then
    Start;
end;

function TPerformanceTimer.GetElapsedTicks: TLargeInteger;
begin
  result := fStopCount - fStartCount;
end;

procedure TPerformanceTimer.SetTickStamp(var lInt : TLargeInteger) ;
begin
  if fIsHighResolution then
    QueryPerformanceCounter(lInt)
  else
    lInt := MilliSecondOf(Now) ;
end;

function TPerformanceTimer.GetElapsedMiliseconds: TLargeInteger;
begin
  result := (MSecsPerSec * (fStopCount - fStartCount)) div fFrequency;
end;

procedure TPerformanceTimer.Start;
begin
  SetTickStamp(fStartCount) ;
  fIsRunning := true;
end;

procedure TPerformanceTimer.Stop;
begin
  SetTickStamp(fStopCount) ;
  fIsRunning := false;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I guess, showing code will help as there is difference by magnitude of 10^3^2 (wrong multiplication by 1000)

Comment: Just did a small test, a single arithmetic add operation will not even took a single tick half of the time. A loop of 50 add operations will generate 1 or two ticks. So what wrong with using QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: @pstar: 50 add operations is not really much. And there's certainly nothing wrong with `QueryPerformanceCounter`. Please show the code where you are actually measuring as well.

Comment: Your error while timing with a stopwatch will be greater than the error in queryPerformanceCounter.  Of course, coding errors you made could be even greater than that.   Welcome to the lovely world of debugging-timing.

Comment: @Warren, unless Pstar has extremely slow reflexes, I don't think it took over 30 seconds just to halt the stopwatch, so while there would indeed be more room for error in that timing, it wouldn't be 32.5 seconds' worth of error. Pstar, is it possible that the code you're timing really does take just half a second to run, and it just takes a long time for the result to be displayed on the screen so you can notice and press the button on your stopwatch?

Comment: I agree. Something is weird here.

Comment: @pstar, you may want to look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030586/calculating-the-speed-of-routines/6031353#6031353

Comment: Thank you guys, lots of very very helpful information. I think I will avoid using QueryPerformanceCounter for timing purpose. If I do need high precision, I will use RTC or HPET on new OS. @Warren good guessing about my reflexes, but assume we are still talking about human beings, a couple of seconds could possible, but NOT 30 SECONDS. So no vote for you, try again :D. Seems like average human reflex time is about 200 ms after half minute of Google.

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter works perfectly well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post a code snippet demonstrating the problem...but I would assume an error on your part:

```
Milliseconds := 1000 * ((StopCount - StartCount) / Frequency);
```

If you are comparing to a stop watch, you can likely take the easier route and just capture the TDateTime before and after (by using *Now()*) and then use the DateUtils *MilliSecondSpan()* method to calculate difference:

```
var
  MyStartDate:TDateTime;
  MyStopDate:TDateTime;
  MyTiming:Double;
begin
  MyStartDate := Now();
  DoSomethingYouWantTimed();
  MyStopDate := Now();
  MyTiming := MilliSecondSpan(MyStopDate, MyStartDate);
  DoSomethingWithTiming(MyTiming);
end;
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct! I have to admit that the code block I measure is incomplete. So in short, there are other part of the code caused the long delay I haven't thought of, and using Now() I got exact same amount of time span with using QueryPerformanceCounter. You win my vote because in my particular case my hardware working properly, my code to measure the time is working but I didn't measure the right code path. There could lots of reasons why QueryPerformanceCounter wouldn't work, by shouldn't on the scale on my case: half seconds vs about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

This code just works for me, maybe you can try it:

```
  var
    ifrequency, icount1, icount2: Int64;
    fmsec: Double;
  begin
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(ifrequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(icount1);
    Sleep(500);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(icount2);
    fmsec := 1000 * ((icount2 - icount1) / ifrequency);
  end;
```

fmsec is about 499.6 or something like that.

Note: Don't rely on Now or TickCount for small numbers: they have an interval of about 10ms (depending on Windows version)! So duration of "sleep(10)" can give 0ms if you use Now and DateUtils.MillisecondsBetween

Note 2: Don't rely on QueryPerformanceCounter for long durations, because it's time can slowly go away during a day (about 1ms diff per minute)

Comment: Best solution to figure out whether QueryPerformanceCounter itself caused the problem I would say. But as I stated in my comments that QueryPerformanceFrequency did return correct frequency number. So your code will working properly, as I tested.    It is interesting that your code will always return numbers very close to 499.6 on average, and it happened on my machine as well. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 3):

If your hardware supports dynamic frequency scaling, it implies that QueryPerformanceFrequency cannot return a static value continuously describing a dynamically changing one. Whenever something computationally aggressive starts, the adapting CPU speed will prevent exact measurements.

At least, it was experienced with my notebook - as it changed to the higher clock rate, QueryPerformanceCounter based measurements were messed up.

So, regardless of the higher accuracy offered, I still use GetTickCount most of the time for such purposes (but DateTime based measurements are also OK, as mentioned before, except if time zone switches may occur), with some "warm-up" code piece that starts eating up the CPU power so the CPU speed is at its (constant) maximum as the relevant code piece starts executing.

Comment: There are some chipsets, that do not return accurate or even linear timing information even when the CPU speed adaptive features are disabled, even on some desktops. even

Comment: @brezinczky All modern CPU will support dynamic frequency scaling, at least I know Pentium 4 and upwards do support, of course it depends on BIOS or user setting to enable/disable it. But still my conclusion will be that, unless using a dynamically changing QueryPerformanceFrequency, using QueryPerformanceCounter with static value for timing will not working most of the time, make it useless. But of cause using the counter itself for profiler will still useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use an NTP server to sync the PC clock periodically, the PC clock over a large amount of time to adjust the QueryPerformanceCounter "tick" time, and the calibrated QueryPerformanceCounter time for precise time measurements. On a good server where the clock drift is low it means that I have accuracy over time periods to much less than a millisecond and the clock times of all my machines synchronised to within a millsecond or two. Some of the relevant code is attached below:

```
function NowInternal: TDateTime;
const
  // maximum time in seconds between synchronising the high-resolution clock
  MAX_SYNC_TIME = 10;
var
  lPerformanceCount: Int64;
  lResult: TDateTime;
  lDateTimeSynchronised: Boolean;
begin
  // check that the the high-resolution performance counter frequency has been
  // initialised
  fDateTimeCritSect.Enter;
  try
    if (fPerformanceFrequency < 0) and
       not QueryPerformanceFrequency(fPerformanceFrequency) then
      fPerformanceFrequency := 0;

    if fPerformanceFrequency > 0 then begin
      // get the return value from the the high-resolution performance counter
      if (fWindowsStartTime <> CSI_NULL_DATE_TIME) and
         QueryPerformanceCounter(lPerformanceCount) then
        lResult := fWindowsStartTime +
                   lPerformanceCount / fPerformanceFrequency / SecsPerDay
      else
        lResult := CSI_NULL_DATE_TIME;

      if (MilliSecondsBetween(lResult, Now) >= MAX_CLOCK_DIFF) or
         (SecondsBetween(Now, fLastSyncTime) >= MAX_SYNC_TIME) then begin
        // resynchronise the high-resolution clock due to clock differences or
        // at least every 10 seconds
        lDateTimeSynchronised := SyncDateTime;

        // get the return value from the the high-resolution performance counter
        if (fWindowsStartTime <> CSI_NULL_DATE_TIME) and
           QueryPerformanceCounter(lPerformanceCount) then
          lResult := fWindowsStartTime +
                     lPerformanceCount / fPerformanceFrequency / SecsPerDay;

      end else
        lDateTimeSynchronised := False;

      if MilliSecondsBetween(lResult, Now) >= (MAX_CLOCK_DIFF * 2) then
        // default the return value to the standard low-resolution value if
        // anything has gone wrong
        Result := Now
      else
        Result := lResult;

    end else begin
      lDateTimeSynchronised := False;

      // default the return value to the standard low-resolution value because
      // we cannot use the high-resolution clock
      Result := Now;
    end;
  finally
    fDateTimeCritSect.Leave;
  end;

  if lDateTimeSynchronised then
    CsiGlobals.AddLogMsg('High-resolution clock synchronised', CSI_LC_CLOCK);
end;

function SyncDateTime: Boolean;
var
  lPriorityClass: Cardinal;
  lThreadPriority: Integer;
  lInitTime: TDateTime;
  lNextTime: TDateTime;
  lPerformanceCount: Int64;
  lHighResCurrentTime: TDateTime;
  lLowResCurrentTime: TDateTime;
begin
  // synchronise the high-resolution date/time structure (boost the thread
  // priority as high as possible during synchronisation)
  lPriorityClass := CsiGetProcessPriorityClass;
  lThreadPriority := CsiGetCurrentThreadPriority;
  try
    CsiSetProcessPriorityClass(REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    CsiSetCurrentThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);

    // loop until the low-resolution date/time value changes (this will load the
    // CPU, but only for a maximum of around 15 milliseconds)
    lInitTime := Now;
    lNextTime := Now;
    while lNextTime = lInitTime do
      lNextTime := Now;

    // adjust the high-resolution performance counter frequency for clock drift
    if (fWindowsStartTime <> CSI_NULL_DATE_TIME) and
       QueryPerformanceCounter(lPerformanceCount) then begin
      lHighResCurrentTime := fWindowsStartTime +
                             lPerformanceCount / fPerformanceFrequency /
                             SecsPerDay;
      lLowResCurrentTime := Now;
      if MilliSecondsBetween(lHighResCurrentTime, lLowResCurrentTime) <
         (MAX_CLOCK_DIFF * 2) then
        fPerformanceFrequency := Round((1 +
                                       (lHighResCurrentTime -
                                        lLowResCurrentTime) /
                                       (lLowResCurrentTime - fLastSyncTime)) *
                                       fPerformanceFrequency);
    end;

    // save the Windows start time by extrapolating the high-resolution
    // performance counter value back to zero
    if QueryPerformanceCounter(lPerformanceCount) then begin
      fWindowsStartTime := lNextTime -
                           lPerformanceCount / fPerformanceFrequency /
                           SecsPerDay;
      fLastSyncTime := Now;
      Result := True;

    end else
      Result := False;
  finally
    CsiSetCurrentThreadPriority(lThreadPriority);
    CsiSetProcessPriorityClass(lPriorityClass);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer addresses the question of why Pstar's timer measures half a second when the stopwatch measures half a minute.

Comment: regardless relevant to my problem, seems like a nice solution for general timer problem, I like the idea of adjust QueryPerformanceFrequency using PC clock time. But I guess precision will be comprised, less than QueryPerformanceCounter if the Frequency didn't change?