# Accuracy of rdtsc for benchmarking and time stamp counter frequency

Tags: linux, assembly, time, intel

As part of a benchmarking task, I was investigating the different mechanisms that can be used to measure elapsed time. I've finalised on using `clock_gettime`, but I did do sufficient research and testing with the `RDTSC` instruction as well. I have several question regarding the same (based on what I read on several online threads):

- On newer processors (>Pentium 4), the TSC ticks at the maximum frequency of the CPU on the system. Is this correct? In that case is it valid to use the number of ticks and frequency to determine the time?
- If the above is true, it means TSC is unaffected by changes in CPU frequency due to power saving and other features. Knowing this, would it mean the total ticks obtained by using `RDTSC` are NOT the actual ticks used by the sampled piece of code - since the code would run at the frequency of the CPU and not that of the TSC? In addition, does this mean the time obtained by using the TSC ticks and CPU frequency isn't the actual time used by the code piece?
- I'm finding lots of different statements about the synchronizing of the TSC value across cores (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388134/rdtsc-accuracy-across-cpu-cores)). I'm not sure what is correct and I'm guessing it depends on the processor model as well. But can it be assumed to be synchronized among cores on newer CPUs? (This is without using `sched_set_affinity`)?

Do note that I'm not using `RDTSC` due to the various problems associated with it (portability, reliability etc). These questions are just to improve my understanding of how TSC works and of benchmarking in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Invariant TSC means, according to Intel,

> The invariant TSC will run at a constant rate in all ACPI P-, C-. and T-states.

But what rate is that? Well,

> That rate may be set by the
>   maximum core-clock to bus-clock ratio of the processor or may be set by the maximum resolved frequency at
>   which the processor is booted. The maximum resolved frequency may differ from the maximum qualified
>   frequency of the processor, see Section 18.14.5 for more detail. On certain processors, the TSC frequency may
>   not be the same as the frequency in the brand string.

Looks to me as though they wanted it to be the frequency from the brand string, but then somehow didn't always get it right..
What is that frequency though?

> The TSC, IA32_MPERF, and IA32_FIXED_CTR2 operate at the same, maximum-resolved frequency of the platform, which is equal to the product of scalable bus frequency and maximum resolved bus ratio.
>      For processors based on Intel Core microarchitecture, the scalable bus frequency is encoded in the bit field MSR_FSB_FREQ[2:0] at (0CDH), see Appendix B, "Model-Specific Registers (MSRs)". The maximum resolved bus ratio can be read from the following bit field:
>      If XE operation is disabled, the maximum resolved bus ratio can be read in MSR_PLATFORM_ID[12:8]. It corresponds to the maximum qualified frequency.
>      If XE operation is enabled, the maximum resolved bus ratio is given in MSR_PERF_STAT[44:40], it corresponds to the maximum XE operation frequency configured by BIOS.

That's probably not very helpful though. TL;DR, finding the TSC rate programmatically is too much effort. You can of course easily find it on your own system, just get an inaccurate guess based on a timed loop and take the "nearest number that makes sense". It's *probably* the number from the brand string anyway. It has been on all systems I've tested it on, but I haven't tested that many. And if it isn't, then it'll be some significantly differing rate, so you will definitely know.

> In addition, does this mean the time obtained by using the TSC ticks and CPU frequency isn't the actual time used by the code piece?

Yes however not all hope is lost, the time obtained by using TSC ticks and the *TSC rate* (if you somehow know it) will give the actual time .. almost? Here usually a lot of FUD about unreliability is spouted. Yes, RDTSC is not serializing (but you can add serializing instructions). RDTSCP is serializing, but in some ways not quite enough (it can't execute too early, but it can execute too late). But it's not like you can't use them, you can either accept a *small* error, or read the paper I linked below.

> But can it be assumed to be synchronized among cores on newer CPUs?

Yes, no, maybe - it will be synchronized, unless the TSC is written to. Who knows, someone might do it. Out of your control. It also won't be synchronized across different sockets.

Finally, I don't really buy the FUD about RDTSC(P) in the context of benchmarking. You can serialize it as much as you need, TSC is invariant, and you know the rate because it's your system. There isn't really any alternative either, it's basically *the* source of high resolution time measurement that in the end everything else ends up using anyway. Even without special precautions (but with filtering of your data) the accuracy and precision are fine for most benchmarks, and if you need more then read [How to Benchmark Code Execution Times on Intel® IA-32 and IA-64 Instruction Set Architectures](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf), they write a kernel module so they can get rid of two other sources of benchmark error that are subject to much FUD, preemptions and interrupts.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: This might be the best/most and most/best obscure Q&A on StackOverflow. Pleasantly surprised, came here wondering about someone's statements about writing a compiler to do 50x2000 rules matrix processing in under 1 microsecond.